# How can i make PPT Editor in Android

Tags: android

i wanted to make ppt editor App for android,
i am facing problem to start it,if any one have some basic guidelines for starting a app can share.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit Microsoft excel ,ppt and other documents in java using apache poi
here is the link http://poi.apache.org. It is android compatible

Comment: Thanks for reply ,can you give more detail about this ,how can i use it in android ,steps for implement this functionality.

Comment: Here is one for core java ,I hope you can implement the same for android.If not possible let me know http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_ppt/index.htm